# Homeomorphism between the set of invertible matrices and itself

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, analysis, inverse

Consider the set of invertible $n \times n$-matrices $GL_n(\mathbb{R}) = \{A \in M_{n \times n}(R) \mid A\text{ is invertible}\}$. I now want to prove that the transformation

$$f: A \mapsto A^{-1}$$

is a homeomorphism from $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ to itself.

Thanks in advance. I'm not very used to these constructions. It seems that $f$ bijective, simply because of the uniqueness of an inverse matrix, is that so? And if $f$ itself is continuous, then $f^{-1}$ is, because $f = f^{-1}$. But how can I show that f is continuous in the first place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $f(A) = f(B)$ then $A^{-1} = B^{-1}$ and and so $I= A B^{-1}$ and so $B = A$. Hence $f$ is injective.

Since $f(f(A)) = A$, we see that $f$ is surjective.

All that remains is continuity.

One quick way to see this is to note that we can [write](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule#Finding_inverse_matrix) 
$f(A) = {1 \over \det A} \operatorname{adj} A$. The determinant and each entry in the adjugate are polynomials in the entries of $A$, hence smooth.
Since $\det A \neq 0$, we see that $f$ is continuous.

If one is willing to throw a multiplicative norm into the mix, we can see that $f$ is differentiable as well: Suppose $\|H\| < {1 \over \|A^{-1}\|}$, then
$(A+H)^{-1} = ((I+HA^{-1})A)^{-1} = A^{-1} (I+HA^{-1})^{-1}$,
and since $(I+X)^{-1} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k X^k$ for $\|X\|<1$, we have
$f(A+H)-f(A) = -A^{-1} H A^{-1} + \sum_{k=2}^\infty (-1)^k (H A^{-1})^k$. A little work shows that the summation is bounded by $K \|H\|^2$ for some $K$, from which we see that $Df(A)(H) = -A^{-1} H A^{-1}$. (cf. the derivative of $x \mapsto {1 \over x}$ is $x \mapsto -{1 \over x^2}$.)

Comment: Your argument for surjectivity prooves injectivity aswell.

Comment: @LeBtz: Good point.

Answer (score 3):

The [entries of $A^{-1}$ are rational functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Analytic_solution), with non-zero denominator, in the entries of $A$.